# Strange sass behavior, bug?

Tags: css, sass

I was changing my css into sass and came across something quite strange, the height of the .jumbotron wouldn't change, while it was being placed in the css. I than tried some stuff and ended up with something even weirder.

There's a difference in result between

```
.jumbotron
  margin-top: -5em
  width: 80vw
  overflow: hidden
  background-color: rgb(250,250,250)
  height: 90em
```

and

```
.jumbotron
  margin-top: -5em
  width: 80vw
  overflow: hidden
  background-color: rgb(250,250,250)
  height: 90em

.jumbotron
  height: 90em
```

The first doesn't effect the height for some reason, while the second one does, I also tried putting the code from the fist .jumbotron in the second, but the problem returns.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you adding semi-colons after every line?  Have you checked your generated CSS?

Comment: Along with the above comment, be sure that your indentations are all of equal size

Comment: Can you post the relative generated css? Does .jumbotron have `display: block;` or some equivalent?

Comment: The same thing happens for overflow: hidden. When I place it under .jumbotron (the first one) nothing happens and it returns to it's (main.css) default of overflow: scroll, but when I place it in the second .jumbotron it does work.

Comment: I'm using sass, so there are no semi-colons, but thanks anyway. The indentatios are of equal size, thanks as well. I didn't change any display, so they are still on the browser default. The generated css is minified, sorry for that, it looks like this:

Comment: Posting the code gives me error, sorry.

Comment: This kind of problem typically results from some CSS rules being ignored because of some kind of error. For instance, you might have weird invisible characters causing problems. Something coming before or after the rule after concatenation might be causing a problem. There's no obvious problem in what you have posted, so the problem must be coming from somewhere else. You really need to figure out how to post the generated CSS.

Answer (score 0):

My sass version is 3.4.22. Output from compilation of the first case is for me:

```
.jumbotron {
  margin-top: -5em;
  width: 80vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  height: 90em; }
```

And for the second one:

```
.jumbotron {
  margin-top: -5em;
  width: 80vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  height: 90em; }

.jumbotron {
  height: 90em; }
```

Is this CSS what you are trying to receive? What is your output CSS? Maybe you are changing something with `height` between the first and the second declaration of `.jumbotron` in the second case, which means you are overriding height in the first case?

Try to debug you styles using developer tools. Check which rules are affecting the height. Check if browser properly "sees" your CSS. Code maps may be useful.